# Two android manifests in one flavor

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I'm trying to build an app with platform-independent activities, but I also need to build an app that is multiplatform. So, I created the config:

```
 sourceSets {
        getByName("any") {
            // How to add here two manifests: mobile and tv?
            manifest.srcFile("src/platform/any/AndroidManifest.xml")
            java.srcDirs("src/platform/any/java")
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/platform/any/java")
            res.srcDirs("src/platform/any/res")
        }
        getByName("mobile") {
            manifest.srcFile("src/platform/mobile/AndroidManifest.xml")
            java.srcDirs("src/platform/mobile/java")
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/platform/mobile/java")
            res.srcDirs("src/platform/mobile/res")
        }
        getByName("tv") {
            manifest.srcFile("src/platform/tv/AndroidManifest.xml")
            java.srcDirs("src/platform/tv/java")
            kotlin.srcDirs("src/platform/tv/java")
            res.srcDirs("src/platform/tv/res")
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the manifest file in `any` must be always a merge of `mobile` and `tv` manifest files. For now, I have the third manifest file. But sometimes developers forget to add needed `activity` or `receiver` to `any` manifest file and `any` build may be broken or vice versa.

Is there any solution to this?