# Multiple manifests in one source set

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-manifest

In an Android project, how can one add **more than one** manifest into a source set?

For example, I want to merge the manifests of *foo* and *bar*.

`build.gradle`

```
manifest.srcFile 'foo/AndroidManifest.xml'
manifest.srcFile 'bar/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

However, in that case, *bar* overrides *foo*. How is it possible to keep both?

Attaching a comment from Android Developers docs:

```
// For each source set, you can specify only one Android manifest.
manifest.srcFile 'other/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

References:
https://developer.android.com/build/manage-manifests
https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#sourcesets
https://developer.android.com/build/gradle-tips#create-different-versions-of-your-app

Related question: [Two android manifests in one flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75436321/)